# Can you do a 900 without using Tony Hawk's special?

Tags: tony-hawks-pro-skater-1-2

One of Tony Hawk's special moves is The 900 for obvious reasons. However, a 900 is just defined by the number of complete rotations you make. Can other skaters do a 900 by just adding an extra half turn to a 720?

Comment: I think my friends and I were able to (barely) complete a natural 900 without using Tony in the original games.  It wasn't easy though.

Comment: Just a note that the 900 special can be used on *any* character. You just need to customize your special movies. They're not unique to each character.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you can get enough air time, you can spin 900 degrees.
It won't count as the special trick. It will just say 900 Indy for example.